# Effect of an image avatar on user's work with comments

Tags: image, comments, efficiency

I am searching for some study about what is an effect of avatar images in discussion. It is definitely true, that comment with avatar image is better for user's recognition and orientation inside many comments.

So I need some study for my work. I was searching in google scholar and on .. (I forgot name) and nothing. Maybe I was searching for bad sentences...

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked a question closely related to this - [Why Should a User Complete a User Profile?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/69877/why-should-a-user-complete-a-user-profile) - and offered a bounty, specifically asking for studies or research that show what I wanted to prove. i.e. it's better to have avatars and completed profiles.

So I've looked extensively myself, and had several people on here searching, and **failed to find such a study**. Some one or company somewhere has data on this, but it's not readily publicly available.

I agree with you that it's "definitely true" that avatars improve things like recognition, because it's completely obvious to me as a human that this is the case.

But if you really need some data to prove this, you're probably going to have to generate it yourself with some user testing.

Answer (score 2):

> Getting recognized—getting *heard*— is actually tougher than ever.
>   Although there are so many different avenues, networks, tools, and
>   channels available for creating the unique voice—your personal
>   brand—standing out from the crowd is just that much more difficult.
>
> One way you can stand out, especially on sites like Twitter, is to
>   have a great avatar. A great avatar will help people remember you
>   instantly. And you should use it everywhere, across the board. Use it
>   on your blog if you have one (you should). Use it on Twitter,
>   Facebook, LinkedIn, *everywhere*. Even if people don’t automatically
>   remember your name or your website, they’ll remember your avatar and
>   make an association. When they see it again later, on another network
>   or site, they’ll be more likely to pay attention, to *friend* you, and
>   maybe remove a few of those degrees of separation.

Source: [Why Your Avatar Matters](http://hivelogic.com/articles/why-your-avatar-matters)