Why do most comments sections have profile pictures?
Pretty much every comments section I've come across online shows the users' profile pictures. For example, Reddit, Substack etc. But why? I personally don't care one bit what a random commenter's profile picture is. I see hundreds every day, so i don't remember any of them either (in most cases, I can't even recognise my own profile picture if it isn't my face). In most comments sections, a single person only has one or two comments too, so the notion of identifying a user isn't really applicable either.
I saw online that reddit initially didn't have a profile picture either and that they only added this 3 years ago. People don't seem to like it like that either.
This begs the question – why add profile pictures? What value do they serve from a UX standpoint?
Why can't comments sections just be boxes with text? For example, like in this website or Hacker News.

My question was flagged as a potential duplicate. It might be, but is still very much unanswered. This question's answer is only applicable to profile photos that are faces (not the random images on pseudonymous forums like reddit). It also overlooks the fact that in most cases (especially on phones), profile pictures are so small that the distinct facial features/expressions are not clearly visible – hence no meaningful first impressions can really be formed. This other question is tangential – it asks for the benefits of completing general user profile things (information like professional background and interests). I'm specifically wondering why we want to show those tiny circle images beside each comment. You can still give users the personalisation etc by allowing them to have their own custom page and avatar etc, but why do we want that rounded image beside every comment?

same as this https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/70049/97981
